# Flutter The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I keep getting the following error when I run the Flutter run command

```
* Where:
Build file '/Users/Almog/Almog Studio/Almog Studio Products/DogBase/R&D/dogbase-mobile-app/android/app/build.gradle' line: 24
    
* What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    > Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
       > The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated.
         The current default is 'true'.
         It has been removed from the current version of the Android Gradle plugin.
         This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.
```

I'm not using enableAapt2 and I have the latest Gradle version installed here is the gradle file:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dogbase.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.4.10"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Check the gradle.properties if the android.enableAapt2 exist ?

Comment: No its not there

Comment: I only have 
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true